# access to the fetch path when the resp.blob() Promise is resolved

Tags: javascript

I need to fetch several files but I don't know how to access the request url once I have their blobs resolved:

```
paths = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
for (const path of paths) {
     fetch(path)
          .then(resp => resp.blob())
          .then(blob => {
            console.log('path: ' + path) <- I need access to the fetch path here
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
}
```

I need access to the fetch path when the resp.blob() Promise is resolved.
How do I get access to the fetch path there?

Comment: `I need access to the fetch path here` it's `path` ... just like you're doing it

Comment: It appears to only show '3.png' - by the time the promise is resolved - the path is already set to that value of the array - am I wrong?

Comment: It gives me `path: 2.png` `path: 3.png` `path: 1.png`, which looks fine. A `for` loop with `const`/`let` will bind the iteration variable separately, unlike if you use `var`. If I changed the "const" to `var`, I would get `path: 3.png` three times.

Comment: no, it'll show each one as each one is resolved- may not be in the right order ... but the blob will be for the right file - perhaps your real code is doing something different

Answer (score 1):

Below I've simulated the parts of the `fetch` API you're using in the code you showed. You can see that it works according to the expectations that you expressed. How long each individual `fetch` result takes to settle will determine the order of the console messages. (Keep pressing "Run" to experiment and see different, random results.)

```js
function getRandomInt (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function delay (ms, value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms));
}

// Fetching in this sim will take between 0 and 1500 ms
function fetch (url) {
  return delay(
    getRandomInt(0, 1500),
    {
      blob: () => delay(
        getRandomInt(0, 50),
        new Blob(),
      ),
    },
  )
}

paths = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png'];

for (const path of paths) {
  fetch(path)
    .then(resp => resp.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      console.log('path: ' + path);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```